# IE filter statement breaks IE9 background clipping

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I believe all browsers by default use `background-clip: border-box;`. This seems to be default behavior.

When using: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ it specifies filter as the final property. When using IE9 the background bleeds out of the border, and the border-clip property becomes ineffective.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/tPDMb/3/

I ended up just removing the filter statement for now, but that causes ie9 and lower to not have a background gradient at all.

Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in stating the default behavior is to clip to the border box, The initial value of [`background-clip`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-clip) is indeed `border-box`.

The problem is that IE filters are not true CSS background layers. As such, an IE gradient filter will ignore all background and border positioning/clipping properties like `background-clip`, `background-position` and `border-radius`. Unfortunately, this is by design; the only way to get a gradient background working in IE9 and lower while respecting these properties is to use a pre-rendered gradient image. If you need to support older IEs just replace the SVG part that ColorZilla provides with a PNG image or similar.

Comment: woops sorry typo! I fixed it in the question. Thanks!